# Is there a way to print all the pipeline names from a folder in Azure Devops Server -2019

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019

To complete the estimation and scope of the task, our company was asked to obtain a list of all the pipelines. When we looked into that, we saw that there were over 1000 pipelines organized into various folders, but surprisingly, there were no choices to export the names as a list or do anything else that would be significantly helpful.
Are there any available scripts or Pipeline tasks?
Can someone please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

First check the Api version, i am working with the latest one in preview yeah scary :) then you can just perform a get request following api calls:

[Simple get](https://GET%20https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview.1)

GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview.1)

If you want additional parameters to filter:

[Parametrized get](https://GET%20https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines?orderBy=%7BorderBy%7D&$top=%7B$top%7D&continuationToken=%7BcontinuationToken%7D&api-version=6.0-preview.1)

GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines?orderBy={orderBy}&$top={$top}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines?orderBy=%7BorderBy%7D&$top=%7B$top%7D&continuationToken=%7BcontinuationToken%7D&api-version=6.0-preview.1)